# Should tokenizer return language keywords?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, tokenize

I am writing a toy-compiler for a toy-language, let's suppose it has JavaScript syntax.

Let's say that the source file is:

```
var val = 123;
```

My simple compiler will consist of a Tokenizer and a Parser (for now).

Should the Tokenizer return entire language keywords, e.g. `var` or letter by letter (`v`, `a`, `r`) ?

Sooner or later I will have to recognize keywords, literals etc. and I wonder where is the place for this kind of work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tokenizer should usually already return entire keywords (= **tokens**).

There is no disadvantage of doing so: 
As soon as your tokenizer decides that it **is** a language keyword (and not a number or similar), why should you "weaken" this information by splitting something you already **successfully detected** up in parts ;)

So more generally: don't hesitate to let the tokenizer output as large building-blocks as possible - as long as you do not give them any more meaning, which should be left to the parser.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So the language is *encoded* in the tokenizer.. and it should know about keywords, handling of literals and comments?

Comment: glad to help! well if with "handling" you mean "detect", yes, the tokenizer should be able to distinguish them (as far as possible - if your language allows naming variables "var", the tokenizer cannot decide whether it is looking at a keyword or not! :D )

Answer (score 4):

The whole *point* of a tokeniser is to take your input stream (of characters) and give you *tokens* that you can use for grammatical analysis.

Hence you would expect the tokeniser to give you something along the lines of:

```
T_KEYWORD_VAR
T_VARIABLE(val)
T_KEYWORD_EQUALS
T_INTEGER(123)
T_KEYWORD_SEMICOLON
```

Comment: Should it handle comments as well? (as a single element)

Comment: @SirBohumil, tokenisers tend to throw away comments since they're not necessary for the next phase. So yes, it would gather up (for example) a `#` followed by the rest of the line (or `/*` up to the next `*/`), but it wouldn't deliver a token for it. It would just move on to the next token.